# Select2 dropdown double tap on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 4.0.5. On Mobile when i open the dropdown, i have to tap twice to select the value. I am populating the dropdown dynamically.

```
populateSelect2(url, element, key) {

    $.get(url)
        .done((res) => {
            if (res) {
                let data = $.map(key ? res[key] : res, (obj) => {
                    obj.text = obj.name;
                    return obj;
                });
                data = sortBy(data, 'name');

                $(element).select2({
                    placeholder: 'Please select',
                    data
                });
            }
        })
        .fail(() => {
            this.showError(`Failed to call ${url}`);
        });
}


$('#selectId').on('select2:select', (e) => {
    const selected = e.params.data;

    /* // Mobile select2 dropdown
    if (width <= 767) {
        $('#selectId').select2('open');
    } */

    utils.populateSelect2(`abc/${selected.id}/def`, '#selectId2');
});
```

If i remove this `$('#selectId').select2('open');` No dropdown will appear. It shows the values though in Html but it does not show the dropdown itself.